# Swift: overriding typealias inside subclass

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift2

So I was thinking about a custom pattern in my project, but I can't get it to work. The main idea is to change the `typealias` on every subclass to get access to the subclass specific interface.

```
protocol InstanceInterface: class {

    typealias Interface

    var interface: Interface { get }
}

// Baseclass
protocol FirstClassInterface: class { /* nothing here for the example */ }

class FirstClass: InstanceInterface, FirstClassInterface {

    typealias Interface = FirstClassInterface

    var interface: Interface { return self }
}

// Subclass
protocol SecondClassInterface: FirstClassInterface { 

    func foo()
}

class SecondClass: FirstClass, SecondClassInterface {

    typealias Interface = SecondClassInterface // <--- This does nothing :(

    func foo() { print("hello world") } // Swift 2.0 here
}

// Lets say I want to call foo trough the interface
let test = SecondClass()

test.interface.foo() // 'Interface' does not have a member named 'foo'
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or do I misunderstand some Swift concepts here?! I do need to subclass here to not to implement everything from super class' protocols over and over again. Is my little pattern even possible? I'd appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no good workaround for this problem.

The main idea to override the `typealias` would work in this case but consider the following:

```
protocol TakeAndGet {
    typealias T
    func take(value: T)
    func get() -> T
}

class FirstClass: TakeAndGet {
    typealias T = FirstClass

    var property = 0

    func take(value: T) {
        value.property = 4
    }

    func get() -> T {
        return FirstClass()
    }
}

class SecondClass: FirstClass {

    typealias T = SecondClass

    var property2 = "hello"
}
```

If the `typealias` of the `SecondClass` overrides the other one the `take` method would work since it takes a subclass which can be treated as the superclass. But the `get` method cannot implicitly convert `FirstClass` to `SecondClass`. Therefore it is not possible to override a `typealias`.

Now if we want to override the `get` function with `get() -> SecondClass` it wouldn't work since it has not the same signature as the one in the superclass. In addition we inherit the `get` method which results in an ambiguous use:

```
SecondClass().get() // which type gets returned? SecondClass or FirstClass
```

So you have to try a different approach.

Comment: I see the point now. But still there should be some kind of an error or warning if you override the typealias inside the subclass!? I mean it does nothing, even for your example it still would stick to FirstClass inside SecondClass, or am I wrong again? What is the point of overriding typealias?

Comment: @DevAndArtist The point is that a `typealias` cannot be overridden and if you declare a new one with the same name like in `SecondClass` it shadows the other one. This means that `T` is in the scope of `SecondClass` a different type but doesn't change the `T` of `FirstClass`.

Answer (score 14):

Would something like this work for your purposes?

```
class MyClass<T> {

}

class MySubclass1: MyClass<String> {

}

class MySubclass2: MyClass<Int> {

}
```