# How to constraint generic type to another generic type in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I'd like to do something like this:

```
class Config<T> {
  func configure(x:T)
  // constraint B to be subclass of A
  class func apply<A,B:A>(c:Config<A>, to:B) {
    c.configure(to)
  } 
}
```

So later, for example, I can apply a Config to a UILabel:

```
class RedViewConfig<T:UIView> : Config<T> {
  func configure(x:T) {
    x.backgroundColor = .redColor();
  } 
}

let label = UILabel() 
Config.apply(RedViewConfig(), to:label)
```

Or extend Config classes:

```
class RedLabelConfig<T:UILabel> : RedViewConfig<T> {
  func configure(x:T) {
    super.configure(x)
    x.textColor = .redColor();
  } 
}

Config.apply(RedLabelConfig(), to:label)
```

I tried to do it, but I couldn't constraint classes. So I tried with protocols and associated types, but when subclassing I found problems ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138343/swift-overriding-typealias-inside-subclass)) when overriding the associated type.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need the generic parameter `B`?  If your argument `to:` was typed as `A` as well, it could be any subtype of `A`.  Like such:

```
class View {}
class LabelView : View {}

class Config<T> {
  func configure(x:T) { print ("Configured: \(x)") }  
}

func applyConfig<A> (c:Config<A>, to:A) {
  c.configure(to)
}

applyConfig(Config<View>(), to: LabelView())
```

Comment: Thanks! So in this case it seems I don't need two types. I don't know why I supposed that I needed two.

Anyway, in some situations you need two separate types.

If I can think of an example I'll update the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Classes make this way too complicated. Inheritance is almost always a bad idea in Swift if you can possibly avoid it.

Structs, though closer, still make this a bit over-complicated and restrictive.

Really, these configurators are just functions. They take a thing and they do something to it, returning nothing. They're just `T -> Void`. Let's build a few of those.

```
func RedViewConfig(view: UIView) { view.backgroundColor = .redColor() }
func VisibleConfig(view: UIView) { view.hidden = false }
```

And we can use them pretty easily:

```
let label = UILabel()
VisibleConfig(label)
```

We can compose them (like `super`, but without the baggage) if their types are compatible:

```
func RedLabelConfig(label: UILabel) {
    RedViewConfig(label)
    label.textColor = .redColor()
}
```

We can pass them around in data structures, and the compiler will apply the right covariance for us:

```
let configs = [RedLabelConfig, VisibleConfig]
// [UILabel -> ()]
// This has correctly typed visibleConfig as taking `UILabel`,
// even though visibleConfig takes `UIView`

// And we can apply them
for config in configs { config(label) }
```

Now if we want other syntaxes, we can build those pretty easily too. Something more like your original:

```
func applyConfig<T>(f: T -> Void, to: T) {
    f(to)
}
applyConfig(VisibleConfig, to: label)
```

or even closer to your original:

```
struct Config {
    static func apply<T>(config: T -> Void, to: T) { config(to) }
}

Config.apply(VisibleConfig, to: label)
```

The point is that just using functions here makes everything very flexible without adding any of the complexity of class inheritance or even structs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and examples, Rob. Nice solution. I'll consider this alternative. I come from Java so I still don't have the "functional mindset". :)